# Limit of $f$ exists and is different from zero, limit of $g$ does not exist, then does the limit of the product $fg$ exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I don't know if the following assertion is true or false:

$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)=2$ and $\lim_{x \to 1} g(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)g(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Do you mean "thus" when you wrote "else?"

Comment: and do the dot between $f$ and $g$ stands for multiplication or composition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
g(x)=\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}\text{ and }2\ne0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a true statement.  Let's consider sequences.  Suppose $a_{n} = (-1)^{n}$, and $b_{n} = 0$ for all $n$.  Then $a_{n}$ has no limit, while $b_{n}$ has limit $0$, and $a_{n}b_{n} = 0$ for all $n$, so $a_{n}b_{n}$ has limit $0$.

Also, we could have both $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$ without limits, while their product sequence converges.  Let $a_{n} = (-1)^{n}$, $b_{n} = (-1)^{n + 1}$.  Then $a_{n}b_{n} \to -1$, while $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ do not converge.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{x\to1}A(x)=a$ and $\lim_{x\to 1}B(x)=b\ne0$ ($a$ and $b$ finite), then
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}=\frac{a}{b}
$$
Now, if $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)g(x)=l$ and $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=2$, then using $A(x)=f(x)g(x)$ and $B(x)=f(x)$, we get
$$
\lim_{x\to1}g(x)=\frac{l}{2}
$$

Extend it when $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)g(x)=\pm\infty$.

Note that $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\ne0$ is essential for this to work.